# SQL Set containing other subsets question

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph-algorithm

Suppose you have a column X with values {x1, x2...xn}. Now each x contains a set of values {a1...an}.

For example: x1 links to {a1,a3}, x2 links to {a3}, x3 links to {a1, a2, a3}.

I need to create a query that will output for each Xi the number of other X's that have a set contained within the set of Xi i.e. they contain a subset of Xi's set.

Here is a table for the sample input for this example:

[image: table for the sample input for this example].

And here is the expected result:

[image: expected result]. As you can see X1 only contains X2. X2 contains no other x's set. And X3 contains X1 and X2

I can't use any procedural extension (so no PLpgsql) or user defined function. It has to be purely a query from standard SQL.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't think Postgres has a "set" data type, so the question really does not make sense.

Comment: do you mean when you say "x contains a subset of values" to store a comma delimited text in the column X?. Storing comma delimited text in a column is always a bad idea

Comment: No I mean X is linked to the values of the subset. So the rows in the table for this example be . x1, a1 | x1, a3 | x2, a3 | x3, a1 | x3, a2 | x3, a3. Where the commas separate the columns and "|" represents new row.

Comment: Also in response to @Gordon Linoff. Obviously "set and subset" aren't data types.... I thought it was quite clear when I said "subset" I was referring to the set of values that are linked with any x1.

Comment: If you provide some data structures, sample data and expected output, I'll bet you get the answer you need pretty quickly

Comment: Ok I've updated the post to include pictures for the sample data and expected output as tables.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: If your arrays have unique elements they could be considered a set.
See operators here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html, also see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/intarray.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query can do this.
In your record set i added a new row called (X4,A10). I am interested if you are able to find other solutions

```
create table dbo.t(a varchar(10),b varchar(10))

insert into dbo.t values('X1','A1')
insert into dbo.t values('X1','A3')
insert into dbo.t values('X2','A3')
insert into dbo.t values('X3','A1')
insert into dbo.t values('X3','A2')
insert into dbo.t values('X3','A3')
insert into dbo.t values('X4','A10')

-- I have added comments
with cross_prod /*I am building the combination of elements of a with the values of other sets..*/
  as (
  select m.a main_a,n.a other_a,n.b other_b
    from (select distinct a 
            from dbo.t
         ) m
    join dbo.t n
      on m.a<>n.a  
      )
   ,interim_data
   as (
        select  q1.main_a
                ,q1.other_a
                /*Here full_match_flag=0 if all the elements match*/
                ,count(case when q2.main_a is null then 1 end) as full_match_flag 
          from cross_prod q1
        left join (/*This portion gets me the data where the elements match*/
                   select m.a as main_a,n.a as other_a,n.b as other_b
                     from dbo.t m
                     join dbo.t n
                       on m.a<>n.a  
                     where m.b=n.b
                    )q2
            on q1.main_a=q2.main_a
           and q1.other_a=q2.other_a
           and q1.other_b=q2.other_b
        group by q1.main_a
                ,q1.other_a   
       )
select main_a
       ,count(case when full_match_flag=0 then 1 end) as cnt_matches
 from interim_data
group by main_a

+--------+-------------+
| main_a | cnt_matches |
+--------+-------------+
| X1     |           1 |
| X2     |           0 |
| X3     |           2 |
| X4     |           0 |
+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please check if this answers your question and if it does mark it as complete

Comment: yep I just got a chance to look at it now. Will try to understand and let you know :)

Comment: Thankyou for the solution. Overall I think I understand most of it, but would be great if you could clarify what you explicitly mean by "match"? So when you say "all the elements match" What does that mean on the table. Anyways, great work and really appreciate your time for the solution. I will definitely let you know if I am able to find other solutions :)

Comment: In my first part --> cross_prod i get the list of all X1 matching with the others. Eg: (X1,X2,A3), (X1,X3,A1) , (X1,X3,A2) , (X1,X3,A2) same way for X2, X3 . In the interim_data im checking how many of those combinations have all of the elements which match completely. So that would have (X1,X2,A3),(X1,X3,A3). After this the left join checks to see if you got any missing elements (ie the values main_a will be null ) and so its count will be greater than 0, if you got missing elements. In the final step i count those records that have got full_match_flag=0 (ie completely matches).

Comment: My explanation may not be the best :-), I suggest you run each of the blocks separately to understand better the result set. I enjoyed this problem